# How to call a function inside a event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function inside a event. But it is not working.
the clicked div should fadeIn and the other divs should have 50% opacity.

My Jquery:

```
function clickopa ( element ) {
  return $( element ).fadeIn(),
  $( element ).closest('div).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
}

$('.blueDiv').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
$('.blackDiv').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
$('.blackDiv').click ( function(e) {
    clickopa(this);
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="redDiv" style="background:red;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
<div class="blueDiv" style="background:blue;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
<div class="blackDiv" style="background:black;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>
```

Comment: OK. What's the problem? What does "it is not working" mean? That is not an error description. Are you aware that you have a `'` mismatch (look at the syntax highlighting)?

Comment: Also please stop writing "jQuery" at the start of every single one of your question titles; it's completely pointless other than adding needless clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clickopa () {
  $(this).css("opacity", 1); //Just use this inside the function instead of wrapping it inside of another function
                             //Since you aren't hiding the divs, just set the opacity to 1 instead of fading in.
  $( "div").not(this).css("opacity", 0.5); //Don't use fadeTo if you aren't animating
}

$('.blueDiv').css("opacity", 0.5);
$('.blackDiv').css("opacity", 0.5).click (clickopa); //Chain the function calls.
```

Comment: It does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/94/ The black div does not get 100% opacity onclick

Comment: I just edited it because fadeIn() doesn't work if the div is already showing.

Comment: It was close. [Here's the working solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/PRZ5J/) `fadeIn` won't work because, well, it was already faded in! Just not at full opacity.

Comment: How do I add something when clicking on the div. like function(e) { alert("ALERT!"); } ?

Comment: @Rails: Add the statement to `clickopa`. `clickopa` is the function that gets called when you click on the black `div`. Which Javascript book are you using?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be very little point in using a function as it's 2 lines of code if I understand your problem correctly just do the following:

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $('div').fadeTo(0,0.5);
  $(this).fadeTo(0,1.0);
});
```

Hope this helps; chuck a comment if not.

Comment: That's great if he wants to affect **every** `div` in the document, when clicking on **any** `div` in the document. It doesn't seem like that would ever be the robust/desirable solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, maybe he should provide more code. It would be unfair for me to assume he has more code than provided.

Comment: Not relevant. The OP said "the clicked div should fadeIn and the other divs should have 50% opacity" and your code doesn't precisely do this. His example only relates to clicking on a specific `div`, but your code relates to *all* `div`s.

Comment: I am not trolling. If you re-read what I've told you and look at the _live example_ I just gave you to demonstrate that your answer is incorrect, then you may be able to see things in the proper context. Thanks. (Also, it's called "Stack Overflow", not "stack".)